# Finding the $n^{th}$ term of unusual sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sequence: $7,8,10,13...$. Since this is neither an arithmetic sequence or geometric I was not sure how to go about solving. My initial thoughts are that it goes up by $+1$ then $+2$, then $+3$ etc. In which the common difference of those is $+1$. But I am having trouble formulating this into an $n^{th}$ term sequence. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you :)

Comment: Something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961952/how-do-i-find-the-sum-of-a-sequence-whose-common-difference-is-in-arithmetic-pro).

Comment: The sequence of triangular numbers, $T(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i$ which begins $0,1,3,6,10,\dots$ has closed form $T(n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  Your sequence is just the sequence of triangular numbers plus seven.

Comment: Look up , or figure out, how to sum $1 + 2 + 3 + . . . + n$.  Then you should he able to adapt it to your sequence

Comment: I gave the answer (proved in the comments to auscrypt's answer) ***earlier*** and only because he argued that no answer is more valid over  the other without realising that both the solutions are same, you accepted his answer! So unfair!

Comment: @Brozovic The accepted answer is that one which is most helpful for the **asker**. No reason to complain. Besides many people (including me) prefer closed form solutions to recurrence relations. In this case one need not compute all previous terms to obtain a certain one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula would be $a_n = 7+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$; this is just triangular numbers but with a constant added.
In general, questions which ask to continue the sequence are usually arbitrary; there are an infinitude of ways to do so, none of which is more valid than another.

Comment: $$7+n (n-1)/2.$$

Comment: $a_n = 7 + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} = 7 + (1 + 2 + \dots + (n-1))=(7+1)+(2+\dots+(n-1))= a_2 +(2+\dots+(n-1))= \dots = a_{n-1} + (n-1)$

Answer (score 1):

$a_1 = 7$ and $a_n = a_{n-1} +(n-1)$ , $\forall n \ge 2$